# Splash Screen for Android PWA

Tags: android

I am having Angular SPA and service workers are enabled. I have included manifest.json file on my index page.

Now I want to use two different icons

1. When users say Add to Home Screen (Home screen added icon).
2. Splash Screen icon/image (the image that is displayed from the time the app is loaded to the time the page is displayed)

Refer to my code below:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "short_name": "myApp",
  "theme_color": "#1c4cc3",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/logo-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Included this in index.html page**

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Comment: Please read here, how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dan Stef: So you didn't get what my question is??

Comment: I have an idea what your question is, but you do not explain what you tried already, or what errors you get.. Did you read the link I've posted?

Comment: I have edited the entire question now. Please comment

Comment: From my (limited understanding) it looks good. Did you check that the file exists in the right path? Did you restart your webserver? Does the problem exist locally?

Comment: yes, everything is good. Actually the problem is chrome by default picks the splash screen icon from manifest properties. But I want to set image explicitly.

Comment: I found some information, maybe it helps: There are 2 layouts for splash screens. You get the "small icon layout" if the icon you provide is <= 80dp. You get the "large icon layout" if it's over >80 dp. Ideal size for splash screen is 128dp. .. Have a look here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/291

Comment: Ok. thank you. I will look into it..

Answer (score -2):

First, create a drawable resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then apply it to your activity theme in styles(The theme must be assigned to the Main activity):

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```

Finally, apply it to y our activity on the manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/yourTheme"
```

There you go...

Comment: If you are willing to change the icon tho, you must include it in your res directory before publishing, then prompt the user to select one..

Comment: This answer is related to native apps. The author asked for a PWA (progressive web app) solution.

Comment: @teja Is this solution not compatible? As your question is pretty confusing! I don't think my answer helped...I'll delete if you say so..

Comment: I have edited the entire question now. Please comment